# Jest tests fail after upgrading react-native from 0.70.5 to 0.71.3

Tags: react-native, jestjs, expo

After upgrading from expo SDK 47 to 48 and consequently upgrading react-native etc. my jest tests are failing. I found that its specifically after running npx expo install react-native@0.71.3 that the tests fail. The error is "Jest encountered an unexpected token" and the location can be seen in the screenshot. Appreciate any help.
[Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmyDq.png)

My package.json looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start --tunnel",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "test": "jest",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.0",
    "@expo/webpack-config": "^0.17.2",
    "@mui/material": "^5.9.3",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "~1.17.3",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^17.3.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/app-check": "^17.3.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^17.3.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/firestore": "^17.3.0",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.4.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.13",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.0",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "expo": "^48.0.4",
    "expo-build-properties": "~0.5.1",
    "expo-dev-client": "~2.1.4",
    "expo-linking": "~4.0.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.2",
    "firebase": "^9.10.0",
    "npm": "^8.19.2",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-event-observer": "^0.5.11",
    "react-native": "0.71.3",
    "react-native-paper": "^5.0.0-rc.9",
    "react-native-responsive-dimensions": "^3.1.1",
    "react-native-responsive-fontsize": "^0.5.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.5.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.20.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.18.7",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.19.3",
    "@testing-library/jest-native": "^5.3.0",
    "@testing-library/react-native": "^11.5.0",
    "jest": "^29.2.1",
    "jest-expo": "^47.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.1.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo",
    "setupFiles": [
      "./jest-setup.js"
    ]
  },
  "private": true
}
```

babel.config.js:

```
module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
    env: {
      test: {
        plugins: ['@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs'],
      }
    }
  };
};
```

I tried mocking, messing with the babel config, jest config, adding transformer, transformIgnorePatterns etc. but without luck.

Answer (score 1):

This is temporary solution. Find setupTest.js file and add this line

```
global.__DEV__ = true;
global.Promise = jest.requireActual('promise');
```

Comment: How do you explain this fix?

Comment: That the problem was how jest deal with promises in the previous versions compared to the last one. looks like problem in this https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/f1fdc8b9b636e010ae5d5e737fc81a8da8f536d4